# List with multiple TextViews for each item

Tags: java, android, list

For an android application, I needed to create a list that would allow me to enter different things into the same 'item'. For example, each one of the objects in the list would need different information(each with a separate row). Specifically, my app would want the following for each list item: pain location, treatment, type of pain, and some other categories per instance.

This is what I have gathered so far, but it only displays one TextView per item on the list:

```
PACKAGE, Imports, etc.



public class PainLoggerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,   
   OnKeyListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    EditText txtItem;
    Button btnAdd;
    ListView listItems;
    ArrayList <String> painItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    txtItem = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    listItems = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listItems);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    txtItem.setOnKeyListener(this);
    painItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
    painItems);
    listItems.setAdapter(aa);

    }
private void addItem(String item){
    if(item.length() > 0){
        this.painItems.add(item);
        this.aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.txtItem.setText("");       
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v == this.btnAdd)
        this.addItem(this.txtItem.getText().toString());
}
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == 
              KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER){
        this.addItem(this.txtItem.getText().toString());
    }
    return false;

}
```

}

**Some sample code would be appreciated, so I have an idea how to implement suggestions - no doubt, I am still a beginner **

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have multiple TextView items when using the layout "simple_list_item_1" for your Adapter's layout ... that's why they call it "simple - item - 1".

If you want a total of 2 TextViews per row you can use the "simple_list_item_2" but I actually recommend you go with using a SimpleAdapter and creating your own row entry layout file.  It's much more flexible and you can include as many text items, images, check boxes, or anything else you can think of, versus just a couple of text items on a single row.

Food for thought ...

Do a search for SimpleAdapter examples to see how to implement this.  Not a big deal, and you'll find it's a "gift that keeps on giving."

Comment: +1 Learning to create your own list items isn't very difficult and will give you infinitely more flexibility, allowing you to really give your app a custom feel.

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction as the tutorials aren't really helping out....

    `notes = new SimpleAdapter( 
    this, 
    painItems,
    R.layout.main,
    new String[] { "line1","line2" },
    new int[] { R.id.txtItem,
                                R.id.editText1 }  ); 
                                setListAdapter( notes );`

Comment: @Glendon, can you give me a brief overview/sample on how to create a simple adapter and use it? 

In addition, the above code uses editText1 as another textField and i have changed the list(painItems) to be as follows:
`ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> painItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();`